# Slide up menu with UIPresentationController and Tab bar

Tags: ios, swift

I use UIPresentationController  to show my slide up menu, also I have tab bar menu im my application. My slide up menu appears over my tab bar, but I want it to be shown above my tab bar?

So for now it behaves like this:

[image]
[image]

or with some manipulations with frame height:

[image]

but I need it to behave like this:

[image]

My code:

```
class SlideInPresentationController: UIPresentationController {
    private var direction: SlideDirection

    init(presentedViewController: UIViewController, presenting presentingViewController: UIViewController?,
         slideDirection: SlideDirection)
    {
        direction = slideDirection
        super.init(presentedViewController: presentedViewController, presenting: presentingViewController)
    }

    override func containerViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        presentedView?.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
    }

    override func size(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer, withParentContainerSize parentSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        switch direction {
        case .slideLeft, .slideRight:
            return CGSize(width: parentSize.width*(2.0/3.0), height: parentSize.height)
        case .slideUp, .slideDown:
            return CGSize(width: parentSize.width, height: 88)
        }
    }

    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        var frame: CGRect = .zero
        frame.size = size(forChildContentContainer: presentedViewController, withParentContainerSize: containerView!.bounds.size)
        switch direction {
        case .slideLeft:
            frame.origin.x = containerView!.frame.width - frame.size.width
        case .slideUp:
            frame.origin.y = containerView!.frame.height - 88-49 //slide up menu + tab bar
        default:
            frame.origin = .zero
        }
        return frame
    }

}
```

Here, Animation Class and extension of SlideInPresentationAnimator

```
class SlideInPresentationAnimator: NSObject {
    let direction: SlideDirection

    enum AnimationType
    {
        case dismiss
        case show
    }

    let animationType: AnimationType
    var mainViewController: UIViewController?

    init(type: AnimationType, presentingSlideDirection slideDirection: SlideDirection, controller: UIViewController)
    {
        direction = slideDirection
        animationType = type
        mainViewController = controller
        super.init()
    }

    init(type: AnimationType, presentingSlideDirection slideDirection: SlideDirection)
    {
        direction = slideDirection
        animationType = type
        super.init()
    }
}


extension SlideInPresentationAnimator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval
    {
        return 0.3
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)
    {
        let transitionKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey
        switch animationType {
        case .dismiss:
            transitionKey = .from
        case .show:
            transitionKey = .to
        }
        let controller = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: transitionKey)!
        if animationType == .show
        {

            transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
        }

        let inFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: controller)
        var outFrame = inFrame
        switch direction {
        case .slideLeft:
            outFrame.origin.x = transitionContext.containerView.frame.size.width
        case .slideUp:
            outFrame.origin.y = transitionContext.containerView.frame.size.height - 88
        default: break
            // TODO
        }

        let startFrame: CGRect, endFrame: CGRect
        switch animationType {
        case .show:
            startFrame = outFrame
            endFrame = inFrame
        case .dismiss:
            startFrame = inFrame
            endFrame = outFrame
        }
        let animationDuration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        controller.view.frame = startFrame
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
            controller.view.frame = endFrame
        }) { (finished: Bool) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
outFrame.origin.y = transitionContext.containerView.frame.size.height - 88
```

you should also subtract the height of your tab bar

```
outFrame.origin.y = transitionContext.containerView.frame.size.height - 88 - *height of tab bar*
```

I believe the height of tab bar used to be 49, but I haven't used tab bar in a while so probably better to just get the height by using

```
tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but In this case my slide up menu became higher with empty row in the base but still covers tab bar.

Comment: That's because you have only updated the height of presentedController and not the containerView as well. Basically what you want is to have `origin.y` of the view that contains **Load Image** and **Draw Image** (lets call it `viewX`) set to `screenHeight - tabBarHeight - viewXheight`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but mainly setting the constraint for table view height (that is viewX) was the main point in this solution.